Redirect not working after successfully obtaining a google auth token to Calendar
I will apologize in advance if this is because of my inexperience however I am not able to get my redirection to work and I don't know why.  Basically my controller called oauthcontroller has an action getTokens
public async Task<ActionResult> GetTokens(string code)
     {
     var tokenFile = "F:\\DevelopmentFiles\\CalendarTestAPI\\CalendarFrontEnd\\Files\\tokens.json";
     var CredentialsFile =     
     "F:\\DevelopmentFiles\\CalendarTestAPI\\CalendarFrontEnd\\Files\\credentials.json";
     JObject Credentials = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(CredentialsFile));

     RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token");
     RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
     request.AddQueryParameter("client_id", Credentials["client_id"].ToString());
     request.AddQueryParameter("client_secret", Credentials["client_secret"].ToString());
     request.AddQueryParameter("code", code);
     request.AddQueryParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
     request.AddQueryParameter("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:7243/oauth/callback");
     
     var response = restClient.Post(request);
     if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
         await System.IO.File.WriteAllTextAsync(tokenFile,response.Content);
         return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(
       new { action = "Index2", controller = "Home" }));
     }
     else
     {
         return View("Error");
     }
     
 }


in addition my home controller has two ActionResults:
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Index2() 
{
    return View(); 
}

The first action "Index" is originally called by default, a user clicks a button to properly obtain a token from google then once it has it, I want it to redirect to "Index2"  however nothing I've done has worked.  I see this even after the code correctly breaks in debug on and then runs:
  return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(
  new { action = "Index2", controller = "Home" }));' 


The return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(        new { action = "Index2", controller = "Home" })); looks good, how about you remove the google auth part , directly return this inside the GetTokens method?
